# I have written some code and i am trying to use "else" and i keep getting errors

Tags: python, pycharm

ive written some code and it works fine (from what i can see anyway) until I get to the "else" part, really i just want to set up a simple loop but I dont know how. the error is "Statement expected, found Py:ELSE_KEYWORD Statement expected, found Py:COLON"

```
name = input("Hello, what is your name? ")

restart =  input ("Do you want to chat 'y' (type 'y' for yes) or 'n'")
while restart == "y":

 print("Hello " + name)

feeling = input("How are you today? ")

print("I'm feeling good!")

else:
print("Sorry, the restart")
else: print("goodbye")
```

I am just trying to set up my loop then I will finish my code.

Comment: Why are you using `else`? What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Python needs proper indentation, it is part of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things:

1. Python is unique in that *whitespace matters* - code within the same block should have the same indentation
2. Else-statements can only be used following an if-statement. Since you don't have any if-statements in your code, you can't have any else-statements. We can just remove them.
3. You need to ask the user if they want to keep going at the end of your loop.

Here's a cleaned-up version of your code:

```
name = input("Hello, what is your name? ")

restart = input ("Do you want to chat 'y' (type 'y' for yes) or 'n'")
while restart == "y":
    print("Hello " + name)
    feeling = input("How are you today?")
    print("I'm feeling " + feeling)
    restart = input ("Do you want to chat 'y' (type 'y' for yes) or 'n'")

print("Goodbye")
```

Comment: "else" can also follow "while", "for" or "try" blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The loop structure needs to be changed. We need to run an infinite loop and only when user types 'n' we should come out of that loop

[image]

Comment: @BostetCoder would you mind accepting my answer if that solved your problem?